# eofbit set by a formatted input reaching the stream's end (without failure) prevents next formatted output

Tags: c++, serialization, iostream

We are developing a serialization library (inspired from boost::serialization).

Its main intention is to use a single `iostream` for both input and output of application data objects (that are each composed of several "nodes"), while the application is running. The library saves new nodes at the end, but has the ability to load nodes from random positions.

When using a 'formatted output' backend (i.e. using stream's `operator>>` and `operator<<` to serialize as text), there is a special case happening when the last formatted input reaches the end of the stream:

- From [this documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/FormattedInputFunction), it is expected that the formatted input sets the `eofbit` when reading the last value from the stream (as it will have to reach the end to know that the value was read entirely).

  **edit**: Following <s>a comment</s> several comments by Pete Becker, a minimal illustration of the point that a successful formatted input can still set the eofbit is available here: http://ideone.com/SPirIC
- Then, the next formatted output will fail (still according to [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/FormattedOutputFunction)), because formatted output fails if `eofbit` is set.

We are primarily looking for a way to handle such 'edge' case in the most sensible manner.
We could add a check at the beginning of our 'output' function (eg. `clear`ing the `iostream` if `eofbit` is the only bit set), but such check would potentially been run thousand of times when a complete object is loaded, and only a tiny portion of times would it actually make any sense to run the condition body.
Is there an alternative to cluttering the function with this initial step ?

**Bonus question**: What is the rationale for mandating that an output fails when a stream `eofbit` is set. EOF is actually a valid position to write to said stream (as simply clearing the bit, without moving the stream put-pointer, solves the issue).

Comment: Reading **to** the end of the file does not set eof. Attempting to read **past** the end of the file does.

Comment: @PeteBecker: thank you for your comment. Yet a **formatted** input function has to attempt a read past the last character of a stream : by nature it does not know if the value is entirely read until reaching either a whitespace or eof. Eg: http://ideone.com/Is3YPu

Comment: Reading the last entry in a file does not set eof. Attempting to read something that cannot be satisfied without hitting the end of the file sets eof, because the read **failed**. `eof()` tells you **why** the read failed.

Comment: @PeteBecker Well, did you even take a look at the [example](http://ideone.com/Is3YPu) linked in my previous comment ? The read did **not** fail, as the integer was successfully extracted (or we have to agree on the definition of failed reads), yet the statement reading it undoubteldly set the eofbit. **edit:** Here is a fork of the example with an extra print, I actually forgot to show the read was succesfull: http://ideone.com/SPirIC

Comment: @PeteBecker "Reading the last entry in a file does not set eof" It does if the last entry is immediately followed by eof without an intervening newline. The read succeeds *and* the eof is hit.

Comment: @n.m. -- no. A read cannot simultaneously succeed and fail. eof is an after-the-fact indicator: it tells you **why** an attempted read failed.

Comment: @n.m. -- a file that does not end with a newline is not a valid text file.

Comment: @PeteBecker You are the only one ever mentioning files in this whole discussion about streams in general. Your point about validity of text files seems a bit... convenient. Anyway, care to explain why the example http://ideone.com/SPirIC seems to contradict the statement you have been repeating multiple times ?